# How to change the height of an NSProgressIndicator?

Tags: cocoa

By default, cocoa progress bars are slightly fat and I want something a little slimmer, like the progress bars seen in the Finder copy dialog. However, Interface Builder locks the `NSProgressIndicator` control height to 20 pixels and my programmatic attempts to slim down aren't working, as calls to

```
[progressBar setControlSize:NSMiniControlSize];
```

and

```
[progressBar setControlSize:NSSmallControlSize];
```

in `awakeFromNib` don't do anything, and the suggestive looking `NSProgressIndicatorThickness` seen in the header file doesn't seem to plug into any methods that I can see.

What's the trick?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those calls should have worked. In Interface Builder, in the Geometry pane (the one whose icon is a ruler), there is an equivalent control size selector that offers "Regular" and "Small" sizes.

Comment: I don't know why the calls didn't work, but the IB checkbox did. That's an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

in IB

1. select your NSProgressIndicator control
2. in the utilities view select the View Effects inspector
3. press + in Content Filters
4. select Lanczos Scale Transform filter
5. set the appropriate scale value in the Scale row
6. set the Aspect Ratio too if you need to change the height only

Comment: While this works to a limit it can only scale the bar to a set limit beyond which the bar disappears. It doesn't really increase the height it simply scales the progress bar to be larger within the given height. which ends up giving you only half a progress bar. The amount that can be altered using this method doesn't really make that much of a difference if you're trying to make it larger. So if you're Using this method also add a ```Affine Transform``` use the Y Offset adjust the bar but in the end it's gonna end up looking very blurry in comparison to the original.